# Handling POST requests from blocked IP's

Tags: cloudflare

I have a malicious user targeting my site, sending a large amount of POST requests. I have automated systems to block abusing IP's however the problem is I am blocking them within my PHP code via a database. So every post request they make, makes a database call. This is creating a strain. I also do this check in the form of a cooldown.

Since I am using Cloudflare I can not just automatically add abusing IP's to iptables or something, and apache isn't getting the real ip's either.

What is the best way to handle this? I keep blocking IP ranges of VPN's he is using, however the IP being used switches as soon as they get blocked.

Comment: Call his mother?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would if I could, however I only have an IP address on them and that is all.

Comment: Are these requests _automated_? Have you captured one with e.g. tcpdump?

Comment: @MichaelHampton how should I capture them? I do not know the originating IP address via my host, only the Cloudflare ip address. These requests are definitely made via a script, however this is a targeted attack.

Comment: Hmm. There's always [Bad Behavior](http://bad-behavior.ioerror.us/) then. (Disclaimer: I wrote it.) Without seeing a sample of the traffic, though, I make no guarantees.

Comment: @MichaelHampton well if you are interested [here is the access logs that contain post requests](http://pastebin.com/imWdDPJm) to the endpoint they are using. Note: The IP address you see there will be a CloudFlare one, not the bad users actual ip. 

Does this help?

Comment: No, as I mentioned on the web site, the Apache logs don't contain sufficient detail. I would need to see a packet capture, or at minimum a complete set of request headers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is there a method you know of where I could monitor the requests to the specific endpoint live and dump a specific request? I may not know the IP, however I do know what the malicious requests look like.

Comment: @MichaelHampton okay I got the real ip's working with the Cloudflare module. I will provide a tcpdump when they start an attack again. Let me know what you want from the tcpdump

Answer (score 3):

You can see the visitor's actual IP by installing mod_cloudflare.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170836-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-Apache-Web-Servers-

> How do I restore original visitor IP to Apache Web Servers?
>
> To restore the original visitor IP addresses to log files and web
>   applications running on Apache httpd web servers, you will need to
>   install mod_cloudflare. To install mod_cloudflare, follow the
>   installation steps described on our Downloads page.

After that you may block the malicious IPs on the Apache level via htaccess before any request reaches any PHP script.

**Update:**

The Cloudflare downloads page provides ready made packages for common
linux distributions. If your distribution is not supported you may
compile the module for your apache as described here:
https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare

> Option 4: Manual Installation: Debian / Ubuntu
>
> mod_cloudflare has a few software dependencies that need to be
>   installed first:
>
> `apt-get install libtool apache2-dev`
>
> Note: If you find that you are unable to install apache2-dev then you
>   should install:
>
> `apt-get install libtool apache2-threaded-dev`
>
> Next, you should download the mod_cloudflare source to your server:
>
> `wget https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare.c`
>
> Finally, install the module. Depending on your system, the command to
>   run might be apxs or apxs2. So, run one of the below two commands. If
>   you get a "Command not found" when running one, try the other:
>
> `apxs -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c`
>
> `apxs2 -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c`

Comment: Their mod_cloudflare solution works on Ubuntu 12.04 not Ubuntu 14.04 like I am using. It does not support apache2.4, it supports 2.2. I am using 2.4.

Comment: If there isn't a package for your distro you can download the source and compile it for your apache as described here: https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare

Comment: Also Apache 2.4 is supported according to cloudflare.

Comment: Okay I have completed the manual install like instructed and it looks like the IP's are now resolving correctly to the real IP's.

Comment: It's not necessary to use mod_cloudflare with Apache 2.4, since it already includes this functionality in mod_remoteip.